# The project disappear from gitweb after a git push

Tags: linux, git, gitolite, gitweb

I use gitolite to host my source code, and setup a website using gitweb to display all my projects. At the beginning, all projects are shown correctly via gitweb, however, after I modified one project and do a git push, it disappeared immediately from the project list.

Every project, whenever I do a git push on it, it will disappear from the project list of the gitweb. Then if I do a "git clone --bare" of that project and replace the original one, it will be back in the project again...

Anyone encounter the same problem?

p.s. I make a "git clone --bare" and do a "git push", then diff it with the original one, what I get is:

Only in test.git/objects: 86
Only in test.git/objects: af
Only in test.git/objects: f4
Only in test.git/refs/heads: master

a new file with master's commit id is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends:

- how you did the integration of gitweb with gitolite ([see "Interfacing with External Tools"](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/external.html)),
- what exact R rights you did specify for your projects: gitweb cannot be the only user authorized (see the [admin doc](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rules.html#rule-accum)).

"disappear" means the authentication you did enter at the Apache level isn't one of the authorized reader.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I changed the following option in ~/.gitolite.rc:

$REPO_UMASK = 0022;       # gets you 'rwxr-xr-x'

to allow "other" user and group to read the repository and solve the problem :)

Comment: @Vincent: according to https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/gitolite.rc.mkd#_most_often_used_changed_variables, this would be because the user for the httpd process (Apache web server) isn't the one managing gitolite. It would be best to have the same user for both.

Comment: @VonC - I disagree that the web server should run as the owner of the repositories.  If a vulnerability is found in gitweb.cgi, I want my infrastructure to protect me from repository corruption.  It would be best NOT to have the same user, but to have the web server be part of a group that had read access to the repositories.

Comment: @Graham I agree with you. Two years after that answer, I still run environments as one user (because I don't have any right to create others, on the servers I have to operate), but you are right.